# SSIS Project is not opening correctly

Tags: visual-studio, ssis

I have a SSIS project I am trying to open. I have been working on a C# project seperately this week. Now, for some reason when opening the SSIS Package (File>Open>Project/Solution), it opens as C# instead of SSIS. I am using Visual Studio 2013. I have no clue how to get this working right. I have tried restarting VS several times. I have also tried opening it with another SSIS project open to see if that would do the trick. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the project from Windows Explorer rather than Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Open your project in SQL Server Data Tools, not Visual Studio. SSDT is a modified Visual Studio for MS SQL projects (SSIS, SSRS,...)